# Is there any geographical limitation when submiting Google Assistant for Alpha Testing?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have submitted my Google Action to Alpha Testing; i add some users for Alpha testing and they could test the app without any problem.

Then, i added people from other country, but they can't access to the assistant with the opt-in link.

I tried to make a new release, we await many hours, but they can't login at any moment.

We've checked that the assistant is with the same account that have the permissions.

So, i want to know if somebody had the same problem, or if there is a geographical limitation with the alpha testing or something like that.

Comment: I have added people from different geographical regions and they did not have any trouble accessing the app

Comment: A rollout from an alpha release can take a few hours, but I don't think that there's any geographical limitations beyond the top-level platform limitations.